# How do I get Pandas to ignore `#` at start of header line?

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a .fce file in Pandas. The start of the file looks like this:

```
# Forces and moments acting on bodies
# Direction1 = (       1       0       0)
# Direction2 = (       0       1       0)
# Moments around (       0       0       0)
# Boundary regions: 0
#   Time       F1-press        F1-visc       F1-total       F2-press        F2-visc       F2-total       M3-press        M3-visc       M3-total
    1250      1.1630515    0.018437668      1.1814892     0.11872933    0.076623484     0.19535281   -0.079455905  -0.0024483534   -0.081904258
    1250      1.1451982    0.019795173      1.1649934     0.10773641    0.076852597     0.18458901    -0.07645881  -0.0026731929   -0.079132003
```

I have been able to get pandas to ignore the first 5 lines since those are not useful to me. The headers are contained in the 6th line. The issue now is that Pandas is interpretting the `#` as one of the headers and I would like it to ignore this character. `Time` should be the first header.

I am using the command `df = pd.read_csv('DragLift.fce',sep='\s+', skiprows=5)` to read the file. I have found that both `read_table` and `read_csv` work the same for this and have the same issue. Everything works fine except Pandas' interpretation of the header. The output is:

| # | Time | F1-press | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1250 | 1.163051 | 0.018438 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

when I want:

| Time | F1-press | F1-visc | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1250 | 1.163051 | 0.018438 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

How can I get Pandas to ignore the `#`?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As you're doing `sep='\s+'` and the way your file is currently formatted, you will get `#` as a column name. An alternative is to pass `skiprows=6`  and pass `names` as the array of column names either by explicitly passing it or by reading line number 5.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708273/skip-character-when-reading-header-with-pandas-read-csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and easy option, [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) your data after import:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('DragLift.fce',sep='\s+', skiprows=5)
        .shift(axis=1).iloc[:, 1:]
     )

print(df)
```

Alternatively, read the headers with a regex, ignore the lines with `#`, and pass the names manually:

```
import re

with open('DragLift.fce') as f:
    m = next(re.finditer('#([^\n]+)\n(?!#)', f.read()), None)
    names = m.group(1).split() if m else None
    
df = pd.read_csv('DragLift.fce', sep='\s+',
                 names=names, comment='#')
```

Output:

```
   Time  F1-press   F1-visc  F1-total  F2-press   F2-visc  F2-total  M3-press   M3-visc  M3-total
0  1250  1.163051  0.018438  1.181489  0.118729  0.076623  0.195353 -0.079456 -0.002448 -0.081904
1  1250  1.145198  0.019795  1.164993  0.107736  0.076853  0.184589 -0.076459 -0.002673 -0.079132
```

Comment: thank you so much! Both solutions worked perfectly